# Serialize object directly to CData

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need to make a api where in the request body there needs to be a `CData` object. All works exept that I cant figure out how to make my object serialze into a `CData` object. The project is written in the .net-framework.

I currently have the following code.

C#:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DATA")]
public class DATA
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "NAME")]
    public string NAME{ get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "NewDataSet")]
public class CDataSet
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DATA")]
    public DATA data{ get; set; }
}
```

How the xml needs to look after:

```xml
<![CDATA[
<NewDataSet>
    <DATA>
        <ID>007</ID>
        <NAME>John</NAME>
    </DATA>
</NewDataSet>
]]>
```

I can make it working by serializing normally by making a request to this function:

```
public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T toSerialize)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());

    using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Than manual adding the `CData` parts around it.

However my boss wants it make it work without manually adding the parts.

Please note I'm very new to C#.

Any step in the right direction will help. Thanks!

Comment: So, we are supposed to do your work of reading the manual? Note that odata is NOT USING XML. It is Json based. Start with reading - C# and... the odata specs. And using a odata client side framework ,because dealing with it manually is a pain. Trivial when you use a toolkit.

Comment: CDATA can not be the root element of the xml. It must be nested in another element.

Comment: If you haven't solved the problem yet, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CDataSet data = new CDataSet()
            {
                data = new DATA() { ID = "007", NAME = "John" }
            };
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CDataSet));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            stream.Position = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            string output = string.Format("<![CDATA[\n{0}\n]]>", xml);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DATA", Namespace = "")]
    public class DATA
    {
        private int _ID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
        public string ID {
            get { return _ID.ToString("D3");}
            set{  _ID = int.Parse(value);}
        }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "NAME")]
        public string NAME { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "NewDataSet")]
    public class CDataSet
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DATA")]
        public DATA data { get; set; }
    }
}
```